# can't read a public scalar inside a sub

Tags: xml, perl, shared, subroutine, xml-twig

the perl code is like followed : the problem is that I can not read $key inside sub tweak_server{} ....

```
my $key;
my %hash = ( flintstones => [ "C:/Users1/f1.xml", "C:/Users1/f2.xml" ], 
            jetsons => [ "C:/Users2/f1.xml" ], 
            simpsons =>    [ "C:/Users3/f1.xml", "C:/Users3/f1.xml", "C:/Users3/f1.xml" ], ); 

foreach $key (keys%hash){
if (scalar@{$hash{$key}}>1){
    foreach my $path (@{$hash{$key}}){
        my $filehandle;
        open($filehandle, "+<$path") or die "cannot open out file out_file:$!";
        my $roots = { TAG => 1 };
        my $handlers = { 'ROOT/TAG' => \&tweak_server,
                    };
        my $twig = new XML::Twig(TwigRoots => $roots,
                             TwigHandlers => $handlers,
                             twig_print_outside_roots => \*$filehandle);
        $twig->parsefile($path);
        say $key;#could read key
        sub tweak_server {
            my ($twig, $root) = @_;
            my $tag2=$root->first_child_text('TAG2'); 
            say $key;# could not read
            if ($tag2=~/$key/){
            #BLABLA
            }
            $twig->flush( $filehandle, pretty_print => 'indented');
        }
    }
}
```

}

as i state, the $key can be read outside the sub, but not inside..the error appeared:Use of uninitialized value $key

and then i tried a simple situation, just like

```
my $a="aaa";
open( $filehandle, "+<$path") or die "cannot open out file out_file:$!";
my $roots = { TAG => 1 };
my $handlers = { 'ROOT/TAG' => \&tweak_server,
            };
my $twig = new XML::Twig(TwigRoots => $roots,
                     TwigHandlers => $handlers,
                     twig_print_outside_roots => \*$filehandle
                     );
$twig->parsefile($path);
sub tweak_server {
    say $a;
    my ($twig, $root) = @_;
    my $tags=$root->first_child_text('TAG2');
    my $str="204B";
    if ($tag2=~m/$str/){
    foreach my $b(1...6){
                    say $a;             }
}
$twig->flush( $filehandle, pretty_print => 'indented');

}
```

in this code, the $a can be read....
i spent one day on this, but still can't fix it...crazy now
thank in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring `$key` outside of the `for` loop. Then, inside the for loop, you define a subroutine that closes on `$key`.

As a general rule, declare variables in the smallest applicable scope. For example:

```
for my $key (keys ...) {
```

or

```
open my $filehandle, '<', ...
```

Why are you defining `sub tweak_server` in the body of the `for` loop? It seems to me, what you want to do is to define a new anonymous sub for each iterationn.

First, a short example that replicates what you are observing:

```
use warnings; use strict;

my $key;
my %hash = qw(a b c d e f);

foreach $key (keys %hash) {
    somesub();
    sub somesub {
        print "$key\n";
    }
}
```

Now, the fix:

```
use warnings; use strict;

my %hash = qw(a b c d e f);

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    my $somesub = sub { print "$key\n" };
    $somesub->();
}
```

This way, we define a new anonymous function at each iteration and each new sub closes over each value of the loop variable.

In terms of your code, you should then replace the named sub with

```
my $tweak_server = sub {
    my ($twig, $root) = @_;
    my $tag2=$root->first_child_text('TAG2'); 
    say $key;# could not read
    if ($tag2=~/$key/){
        #BLABLA
    }
    $twig->flush( $filehandle, pretty_print => 'indented');
}

my $handlers = { 
    'ROOT/TAG' => $tweak_server,
};
```

Or, even better, as @mirod observes, pass `$key` to `tweak_server`:

```
sub tweak_server { 
    my( $key, $twig, $root)= @_;
    ...
}
```

And, in the body of the loop,

```
my $handlers = { 
    'ROOT/TAG' => sub { tweak_server($key, @_) },
};
```

Comment: I would actually have the handler be `'ROOT/TAG' => sub { tweak_server( $key, @_); }` and then get the key in tweak_server: `sub tweak_server { my( $key, $t, $root)= @_; `

Answer (score 4):

Short version: If you have a named sub declariation (`sub foo { ... }`) inside of another sub or inside of a loop, you're probably doing something wrong, you probably want an anonymous sub. This is the case here.

---

```
sub foo { ... }
```

is basically the same as

```
BEGIN { *foo = sub { ... }; }
```

If a sub refers to any lexical (`my`) variables outside of itself, they will be captured when the `sub` is executed, which is at compile-time with named subs. A common mistake is to do

```
sub outer {
    my ($x) = @_;

    sub inner {
       ... $x ...
    }

   outer();
}
```

That doesn't work because `my $x` is called multiple times to create multiple variables, but `inner` only captures the one that existed at compile time. (Fortunately, it warns.)

At first glance, your code only has one variable named `$key`, so there should be no problem capturing it at compile time. But they looks are deceiving. Due to foreach's aliasing feature, the iterator variable is not the variable it was outside the loop at all.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $x; say "x: ", 0+\$x;   # Show address of variable.
   my $y; say "y: ", 0+\$y;
   my $z; say "z: ", 0+\$z;
   for $x ($y, $z) { say "i: ", 0+\$x; }
'
x: 155771632
y: 155771584
z: 155771744
i: 155771584
i: 155771744
```

In your case, you had

```
$ perl -E'
   my $x; say "x: ", 0+\$x;
   my $y; say "y: ", 0+\$y;
   my $z; say "z: ", 0+\$z;
   for $x ($y, $z) {
      say "i: ", 0+\$x;
      sub f { say "f: ", 0+\$x; }
      f();
   }
'
x: 142992144
y: 142992096
z: 142992256
i: 142992096
f: 142992144
i: 142992256
f: 142992144
```

You want the sub to capture `$x` at *run-time*, and that's done by using an anonymous sub.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $x; say "x: ", 0+\$x;
   my $y; say "y: ", 0+\$y;
   my $z; say "z: ", 0+\$z;
   for $x ($y, $z) {
      say "i: ", 0+\$x;
      my $f = sub { say "f: ", 0+\$x; };
      $f->();
   }
'
x: 159675200
y: 159675152
z: 159675312
i: 159675152
f: 159675152
i: 159675312
f: 159675312
```

---

Fix:

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
   if (@{ $hash{$key} } > 1) {
      for my $path (@{ $hash{$key} }) {
         open(my $fh, "+<", $path)             # +< ???
            or die("Can't open \"$path\": $!\n");

         my $tweak_server = sub {
            my ($twig, $root) = @_;
            ...
         };

         my $twig = new XML::Twig->new(
            TwigRoots => { TAG => 1 },
            TwigHandlers => { 'ROOT/TAG' => $tweak_server },
            twig_print_outside_roots => $fh,   # No need for \*$fh
         );
         $twig->parsefile($path);
      }
   }
}
```

You could also use an anonymous wrapper that passes the variables as arguments to a named sub.

```
sub tweak_server {
   my ($fh, $key, $twig, $root) = @_;
   ...
}

for my $key (keys %hash) {
   if (@{ $hash{$key} } > 1) {
      for my $path (@{ $hash{$key} }) {
         open(my $fh, "+<", $path)             # +< ???
            or die("Can't open \"$path\": $!\n");

         my $twig = new XML::Twig->new(
            TwigRoots => { TAG => 1 },
            TwigHandlers => {
               'ROOT/TAG' => sub { tweak_server($fh, $key, @_) },
            },
            twig_print_outside_roots => $fh,   # No need for \*$fh
         );
         $twig->parsefile($path);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!! i will try the second way. and you are right, i shouldn't use  +< , it should be +>>.

Comment: @trivial, appending an XML document to something is odd, but even then it would be `>>`.

Comment: i try the second way to passes the variables as arguments to a named sub, but it doesn't work...

Comment: i use the first way and it works, and i finally use +<. thank you~

Comment: @trivial, The second one works. Maybe you changed something? Make sure to always use `use strict; use warnings;` in your code. And by the way, it's proper StackOverfow etiquette to approve deserving answers.